# Application has iAd Configuration error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, iad

I am developing a simple application in that one i implemented iAd Banner View. and I have no errors in my code if i run that code i got error
"The Operation Could n't be Completed.Application has iAd Network Configuration error" i want to know what is reason behind the error. and i'm using XCode 4.2 and iOS 5 Simulator.

This is the Code What i wrote.

```
-(void)moveBannerViewOffScreen
{
   CGRect originalTableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
   CGFloat newTableHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
   CGRect newTableFrame = originalTableViewFrame;
   newTableFrame.size.height = newTableHeight;

   CGRect newBannerFrame = self.bannerView.frame;
   newBannerFrame.origin.y = newTableHeight;

   self.tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
   self.bannerView.frame = newBannerFrame;
}

-(void)moveBannerViewOnScreen
{
   CGRect newBannerFrame = self.bannerView.frame;
   newBannerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newBannerFrame.size.height;

   CGRect originalTableFrame = self.tableView.frame;
   CGFloat newTableHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - newBannerFrame.size.height;
   CGRect newTableFrame = originalTableFrame;
   newTableFrame.size.height = newTableHeight;

   [UIView beginAnimations:@"BannerViewIntro" context:NULL];
   self.tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
   self.bannerView.frame = newBannerFrame;
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   [self moveBannerViewOffScreen];
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error    localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [alert show];
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
   [self moveBannerViewOnScreen];
   NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: Did you complete the agreements required for iAd in itunes?

Comment: @ahmedalkaff No What are the Agreements Can u please explain?

Comment: Look at the get started steps and follow themL: https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/

Comment: I Developed this Application By watching WWDC iAD integration Video Tutorial.

Comment: "To Use iAd In Your Application, You Must Join the iAd Network" This is from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: is it necessary to join in iAd Network for showing a small demo.?

Comment: @Suresh I think App / iAd are having issues. You should still be seeing a test ad regardless of if your contract is completed. I've been having the same issue.